# Differences between folders

Tags: c#, git, github-for-windows

I need to add a feature in my .NET app that allows users to understand which changes they made to configuration files. Every configuration is archived in folder. Eg.

- ConfigV001
- ConfigV002
- ...
- ConfigV100

I think I could use **git diff** as follow:

```
git diff ConfigV001 ConfigV001
```

to get differences but then how can I format the output to obtain something like this? (the screenshot it taken from [github-for-windows](http://windows.github.com))

[image]

I would have the list of changes between the 2 versions (added, updated, removed files) and the changes for each file

Comment: Why not connect the github for windows application to your local repository? You *can* use github for windows for pure git repositories that will never be connected with github.

Comment: I don' have a git repository. I just mention **git diff** and **github for windows** to show you which is the result I would like to reach

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Diff.NET](http://www.menees.com/index.html); includes source code for the utility and screenshots showing comparable behavior to what you're looking for.